# Store the $_REQUEST data and retrieve it after the page refresh (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a page with PHP and HTML and I have a problem :

First of all, I created a login system : the $_SESSION setting of PHP can be used.

I created a form on a HTLM page where you enter text (this form uses the POST method) :

```
<form method="POST" action="home.php">

<textarea rows = "5" cols = "60" name = "my_text" id="my_text">
</textarea>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you click on submit, it sends the data on another page (PHP page) and it shows it in a box (with the help of PHP).

```
<?php
  echo "<p>" . $_REQUEST["my_text"] . "</p>";
?>
```

Someone knows how to save this data and retrieve it after a refresh of the page ? Must I use the $_SESSION setting ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: sessions would be way to go forward because keep in mind the moment you php script comes to last execution line it terminates and purges what it did previously.  Sessions enable php to save information in file and send cookies on client and retrieve on next connection attempt consequently retrieving stored data. there is lot that goes on behind the scene so yes sessions would be way to go forward.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for this answer.